# Epplus Exception thrown by the target of invocation

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, epplus

I am having problems with configuring the EPPLus library in my script task(C#) SSIS package.
the following piece of code is throwing the error.

```
 using (var p = new ExcelPackage())
        {

            p.SaveAs(new FileInfo(@"C:\Users\..\Documents\myworkbook.xlsx"));
        }
```

I have tried changing the .Net target version for the script but nothing seems to work.
Removing that block of code the script runs fine. 
EPPlus is version 5.1.1

Comment: EPPlus changed licensing model from v4 to v5, and now if you haven't followed the licensing instructions then attempting to use it will throw an error. Have you definitely done the licensing setup on whatever machine is running this code? I've never licensed v5 on my machine, and I just threw your code into a new console app in my VS: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SZgaj.png

Comment: I haven't set up any licensing. Its on my personal machine. I thought on personal machines it doesn't require any licensing setup.

Comment: It requires licensing still, it’s free for personal use, but there’s still something you need to do. https://www.epplussoftware.com/Developers/LicenseException Has details; it’s like a one line setting/code file etc. It also says the licensing exception is only thrown if a debugger is attached which might or might not apply to your scenario..

Comment: THe other thing you can test- comment out the save line. It might be throwing a permission or directory not found error. If the code works with it commented out we have something to go on

Answer (score 2):

use this line If you use EPPlus in a noncommercial context -
`ExcelPackage.LicenseContext = LicenseContext.NonCommercial;` then you can
go to next step -
`using(var package = new ExcelPackage(new FileInfo("MyWorkbook.xlsx"))){}`